# Can you please help me transform this script to adequate to mobile touch in unity?

Tags: unity, input, touch

My code here works with a keyboard:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
  if (transform.position.y < 1.662f) {
    transform.Translate (0, 0.26F, 0);
  }
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
  if (transform.position.y > 1.142f) {
    transform.Translate (0, -0.26F, 0); 
  }
}


if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
  if (transform.position.x < 3.681f) {
    transform.Translate (0.46f, 0, 0);
  }
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
  if (transform.position.x > 3.221f) {
    transform.Translate (-0.46f, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

How could I transform it so that it works as touch input?

Comment: I'm not used to Unity for mobile (actually I've never used it). BUT I think you need to: possibility one: create buttons in your interface so the player can press. Or possibility two: use Input.GetTouch and Touch.position and verify the results and relate to the position in the screen.

Comment: Or alternatively, use the mobile input script that comes with the standard assets package.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have a virtual joystick with 4 buttons arranged like 'wasd' keys with names 'up','down','left','right'.
Now, do this:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
 Ray ray = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
 RayCastHit hit;
 if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)
 {
  if (hit.gameObject.name == "up" && transform.position.y < 1.662f)
  {
   transform.Translate (0, 0.26F, 0);
  } 
  else if (hit.gameObject.name == "down" && transform.position.y > 1.142f)
  {
   transform.Translate (0, -0.26F, 0);
  }
  else if (hit.gameObject.name == "left" && transform.position.x > 3.221f)
  {
    transform.Translate (-0.46f, 0, 0);
  }
  else if (hit.gameObject.name == "right" && transform.position.x < 3.681f)
  {
    transform.Translate (0.46f, 0, 0);
  }
}}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi Geo Baby ,thanks for your help but when i  tried your code , it show an error 'UnityEngine.RaycastHit' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject'

Comment: Hi Farouk, try hit.collider.tag or hit.collider.name or hit.collider.gameObject.name.

Comment: It seems you could have easily looked this up in the API instead of *guessing*, and providing incorrect code. ***Your example accesses `RayCastHit.GameObject`; `RayCastHit` does not exist, and `RaycastHit` does not contain a game object reference***.